# Responsive grid with different column heights

Tags: css, grid-system

Is there a simple way to line up some different sized boxes in a grid and make them responsive?

I've heard of using masonry but I'm looking for something a bit simpler. This is 800px long with everything divisible by 200px on both height and width:

[image]

Comment: Please ask questions if there is a bug or smth in your code. Please do some stuff and ask question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` to create this type of layout.

```css
body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.a, .c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
}
.b {
  flex: 2;
  background: #CC6699;
}
.a .box:nth-child(1) {background: #FF9933;}
.a .box:nth-child(2) {background: #33CCFF;}
.c .box:nth-child(1) {background: #CCCCCC;}
.c .box:nth-child(2) {background: #33CC66;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue I have with it however is that if I change the height of .content to e.g. 400px resizing the browser causes the blue and green boxes to get lost. Is it possible to use this technique with a different height to 100vh?

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you set fixed height.